# merge master branch changes to new branch

Tags: git, github

New features are added continuously on master branch. I am working on different branch. But I only want to merge new added features to my branch. I don't want  to overwrite changes I made with master branch.

Answer (score 0):

I think doing a `git pull <remote-name> master` would do the trick.